# Azure App Service gives SSL connection error randomly

Tags: azure, ssl, redirect, sitecore, paas

We have Sitecore 9 setup on Azure as PAAS. We have multisite environment where one Sitecore instance has 3 websites in it. We have domains for the websites like below:

1. example.com
2. www.example.com
3. 123.com
4. www.123.com
5. xyz.com
6. www.xyz.com

We initially had 3 wildcard SSL certificates cover each (bare domain and www). We have redirection on IIS level to redirect bare domain to www.

Issue
Our websites are randomly giving SSL connection error when hitting https://example.com or https://123.com. Somehow the SSL is not valid (randomly) and it does not redirect to www version too.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is the exact browser warning you are getting? And what cert is being served in that handshake?

Answer (score 0):

This issue might be caused by other security appliance both infrastructure and application level try disabling them for a moment and see if it helps, and try to access website from different browsers, check time and date of machine.
Note: if you are turning security appliances off don’t forget to turn them ON.